# Prints all the numbers from nums in order until the sum of the numbers printed exceeds 100

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am a few weeks into learning python properly and couldn't find a way to proceed from what I currently have. The question is:

> The following function takes a list of numbers nums and prints all the numbers from nums in order until the sum of the numbers printed exceeds 100. This function is written using a for loop and a break statement. The style guide for this course recommends not to use break statements. Rewrite the function using a while loop with no break or return statements and paste it into the answer box. Note: if the sum of the numbers is less than or equal to 100, then all numbers in the list are printed.

```
def print_hundred(nums):
    """Rewrite me!"""
    total = 0
    for n in nums:
        total += n
        print(n)
        if(total > 100):
            break
```

My rewritten code so far:

```
def print_hundred(nums):
    """Rewrite me!"""
    result = []
    while sum(nums) <= 100:
        result += nums
        result += 1
        print(result)
        
        
print_hundred([1, 2, 3])
print_hundred([100, -3, 4, 7])
print_hundred([101, -3, 4, 7])
```

The tests should output respectively:

```
1
2
3

100
-3
4

101
```

Please follow the requirements and an explanation would be nice :)

Comment: What is your intent for how the new code is supposed to do its thing? In particular: you were given an example that uses a `total` that has an integer value, that represents the sum of the numbers seen so far, and which determines this by repeatedly adding to that value. *Why not keep that approach*? I don't understand what you hope to accomplish by using `sum` repeatedly on *the entire original input*; nor do I understand what you hope to accomplish by using `[]` as the initial value for `result`.

Comment: Hint: You want to process *one* of the values from the original `nums` list, *each* time through the loop, right? So the first thing you should think about is *how to get that value* using a `while` loop. Hint: `nums` is a list; are you familiar with indexing?

Comment: Do you understand why `print_hundred([100, -3, 4, 7])` outputs that?

Comment: Sorry if my code is complete junk I got confused around about the result += nums part. I am familiar with indexing. I am also questioning why print_hundred([100, -3, 4, 7]) outputs 101 but I guess I have to go with that as this is for a quiz.

Comment: Nope, that is the wrong approach. Sure you can copy paste the answer into your quiz but if you don't understand the simple **ideas**, there is no way to understand **code**. So, my humble recommendation is try to fully understand the question and sample outputs first. Code will naturally follow, without exception. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate the `for` loop example a bit to reach the desired output with `while` loop. You should consider the size of each array as well as a condition in your `while` loop.

```
def print_hundred(nums):
"""Rewrite me!"""
total = 0
i = 0
while total <= 100 and i < len(nums):
    total += nums[i]
    print(nums[i])
    i += 1


print_hundred([1, 2, 3])
print_hundred([100, -3, 4, 7])
print_hundred([101, -3, 4, 7])
```